# How to get prerequisites for gettingstartedwithdjango.com tutorial?

Tags: python, django, prerequisites

I'm following the tutorial "Getting Started With Django" on gettingstartedwithdjango.com. I'm at the prerequisites on a VM that runs Precise64. The maker supplies a shell script named postinstall.sh. Executing that, it tries to install, among others, ruby1.8.7 but fails to download it. After that it wants to install net-ssh-gateway, mime-types, chef and puppet, which all fail, because they need ruby2.0 or 2.2.
So i've done "apt get install ruby", which got me ruby1.8. I've tried to get a newer version, but it couldn't be found. When I run the script again it still fails to install the apps, that need ruby. And installing them via "apt get install" only works for puppy, the others are unknown.
I would love to do the tutorial, but I fear this applications or libraries are needed.

So how do I get those libraries/applications installed?

Comment: That tutorial is over five years old. Precise64 has been end of life for over a year. I would suggest looking for a different tutorial instead of struggling to get this one to work.

Comment: *"Sadly, this series ended early, too, struck down by careers and time constraints. Kenneth still creates educational content but Getting Started with Django is, for all intents and purposes, purely for archival purposes now."*  maybe try here instead https://www.djangoproject.com/start/ Among other things if you are just trying to learn django then puppet and chef are not needed (nor is ruby)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers. So I will leave it at that and maybe will get me a book or sth. .